# Generating TypeORM migration in Express.js TypeScript app using CLI and .env

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typeorm

I have a TS Express.js app using typeorm and storing the DataSourceOptions in .env (password etc.).

Whenever I try to generate a migration after updating a entity file I'm getting na error that `Error: SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string`
I assume it's because I'm using password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD` in my DataSourceOptions.

My question is if it's possible to call from terminal:
`npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:generate src/database/migrations/migration-name -d src/database/data-source.ts` with .env?